# C# Download Data using Web Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, sitecore

I'm having an issue downloading a file.  I'm running this website on my local IIS.  The BaseUrl correctly has the address of my local IIS site.  The moduleImgPath is a Sitecore media item:  "/sitecore/shell/~/media/Racking/module-image.png".  The BaseUrl has the structure `"http://local-$company.com".`

The code used for the download is essentiall shown below.  The method errors on Image.FromStream() with a System.ArguementException - "Parameter is not valid."

```
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(new WebClient().DownloadData(RackingConfigHelper.BaseUrl + moduleImgPath));

        Image objImage = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

My question essentially revolves around - can you use a WebClient this way, to download data from what essentially a local source?  Or will I need to deploy this code to my test environment to test it out?  If I can, do I need to worry about ports?

Comment: WebClient.DownloadData returns a byte[]. I would save this first to a local byte[] and try use that as argument to MemoryStream.

I know this sounds bizarre but just try it and see what happens...

Comment: It will also allow you to see if the byte[] is filled

Comment: the error is thrown, so that doesn't seem to happen.  The byte array does have data, so it seems to be more so that the data isn't formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your image data is not a jpg (I think this is typically what is expected for Image).

You can see why the error happens on this [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx)

and you can see the docs for Image on this [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx)

I would hazard a guess you are either trying to use a non-jpg OR perhaps the jpg you have may be unusually formed.